Short story about a space traveller on a planet of people, each immensely talented
This was a story in an YA anthology of science fiction stories that I was gifted about 1967-8.
The space traveller discovers a planet where every person is a gifted actor, singer, musician, painter, dancer. Everyone does advanced maths and science. He feels that he has nothing to offer them. They reassure him that he is the most important person on the planet, for none of them have had an audience before.

When I saw the title, I immediately thought of Rimmer visiting the Holoship. Not it, of course.

I suspect that this is Robert Silverberg's short story The Man of Talent, first published in 1956. It is a somewhat autobiographical tale - Silverberg was attending an SF con, and felt himself to not be in the same league as other attendees such as Theodore Sturgeon, Fred Pohl, and Harlan Ellison.
From this excellent summary:

a noted poet seeks an out of the way planet where he hopes to practice
his art. The locals keep inviting him to their social functions though
they note he’s only a poet. He thinks they’re just dismissing poetry’s
value, but it turns out they are almost universally multi-talented:
painters, poets, composers. His only value to them is as an audience
(and they don’t find his poetry that good). He resolves to be an
audience but continue to produce poetry for his sole amusement.

As one of the hyper-talented artists explains when the poet announces his intention to leave, “True, we need no more poets. But we need you. Vilar, we need an audience!”
The story can be read at the Internet Archive, in The collected stories of Robert Silverberg. Volume one.

Thank you so much for this lead to what must certainly be the story I seek. The theme of the story is one I have felt keenly, as an adolescent and as an adult, surrounded by very talented people, learning that being a good audience is also a role in the arts, and in business, and in any creative endeavour. I hope  to recommend it to colleagues still teaching.

Glad to help @IanLindsay If you think my answer is correct, can you click on the green checkmark to "Accept" it? Then people will know that the question is answered. Thanks!
